# Longest time before a Number One Single?

Tags: chart-success, number-ones

Who managed the longest period between their first ever release & their first number 1 single?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Louis Armstrong made his first recording as bandleader in 1925. His single Hello Dolly reached number 1 in 1964.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like, in the US it was Santana with 'smooth':

> The record for the longest wait from an artist's Hot 100 debut entry to its first #1 belongs to Santana, with 30 years between the time he first cracked the Hot 100 with "Jingo" (October 25, 1969) and the first of 12 weeks at #1 with "Smooth," featuring Rob Thomas (October 23, 1999).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Billboard_Hot_100_chart_achievements_and_milestones#Gap_records)

In the UK I couldn't find that stats for that but the longest *between* number 1's is The Hollies at 23 years:

> The Hollies went 23 years between their first top hit "I'm Alive" in 1965 and their next top hit, the re-release of "He Ain't Heavy, He's My Brother" in 1988. They had eleven other singles in the top 10 in that interim time, including three singles to reach the number 2 spot.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_Singles_Chart_records_and_statistics#Longest_time_between_number_one_hit_singles_for_an_artist)

Comment: Beats the one I had in mind - Elton John, who's first [solo] number 1 in the UK was Sacrifice, 1990, 22 years after his first release. I'll give it a couple of days before hitting the 'tick' just in case anyone finds a surprise.

Answer (score 2):

A bit outside the requirements (single -> #1), but you can maybe consider anyway :

```
"Sugar Man" by Sixto Rodriguez
```

This song wasn't released as a single but was part of an album in 1970... and didn't really reach number 1 in 2012, but I think almost everyone heard it then on the radio/tv!

You can see why by watching the movie [Searching for Sugar Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Searching_for_Sugar_Man)
 (I can't sum it up... it would spoil the movie & that fascinating story)

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 we have to add Kate Bush to this list.

First UK hit 1978 with [Wuthering Heights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuthering_Heights_(song)).
[Running Up That Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_Up_That_Hill), first released in 1985, eventually made the top slot in 2022, due to its popularity gained from the TV show Stranger Things.

That makes 44 years.

*Oh, I just realised it doesn't count, because Wuthering Heights also went to No 1. I'll leave this here as an honorable mention.*